# Finding files using batch script with multiple wildcards in path

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, filepath

I have need to regularly search a large and changing folder for specific files in sub folders.

Ex: `"C:\some_folder\a_file_value1_value2_some_more_stuff.zip\something_value1_value2_something.pdf"`

I can't seem to grasp the concept of how to burrow down using the nested for loop method i have found before.

This is what i have right now:

```
set J=1234
set P=alpha
for d/ %%D in (...\Test_Folder\*%P%_*) do for %%F in (%%~fD%J%*.zip\somethingstatic_*.pdf) do echo %%~fF
```

Can someone tell me what how to correctly resolve the wildcard issue in the file path?

Comment: If you open up a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information, you'll gain more knowledge. **_Things like its option `/d` should never be written as `d/`_**.

Comment: That was a typo on my part and i didn't catch it. My script has it the correct way /d.

Comment: If you have an issue with some written content on your electronic internet enabled device, why would you not just copy and paste it into your question to prevent introducing one or more potentially different issues?

Comment: That `*.zip` - is that a real folder or an actual `.zip` file (which the Explorer displays like a folder)?

Comment: `for /D` cannot iterate through the contents of a ZIP file, which is not a folder (although displayed in Explorer as "Compressed Folder"); you will need a command or tool to read ZIP files…

Comment: Compo, my apologies as this question was written on my personal computer, where as the task i am trying to complete is on my work computer. I will endeavor to review my questions more thoroughly in the future. 

Thank you for the information @Stephan and aschipfl that helped out